# Getting Related Info About Categories Return Nothing

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to create a page that will display the names of all the main categories that aren't = `0` and are based off of the first category id.

so it will print out like:

```
3D Models > Animals > Farm
```

I cannot figure out how to do it. I was thinking about just casting each one related to the main category we are on into an array and then reverse printing that out but I'm not sure if this would be the most efficient/correct method to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

dataQuery():

```
function dataQuery($query, $params) {
$queryType = explode(' ', $query);

// establish database connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();
}

// run query
try {
    $queryResults = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $queryResults->execute($params);
    if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
        $results = $queryResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
    $queryResults = null; // first of the two steps to properly close
    $dbh = null; // second step to close the connection
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
    echo $errorMsg;
}
}
```

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `main` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `main`, `name`) VALUES
(2, 0, '3D Models'),
(1, 0, 'Sound FX'),
(5, 0, 'Textures'),
(3, 2, 'Animals'),
(4, 2, 'Comic Book Characters'),
(6, 3, 'Farm');
```

Controller:

```
<?php 

// Load Language File
include_once(DIR_CATALOG.DIR_LANGUAGE.LANGUAGE."/".DIR."/".FILE.".php");

// Load Model File
include_once(DIR_CATALOG.DIR_MODEL.DIR."/".FILE.".php");

$site_title = $text['site_title'];
$page_title = $text['page_title'];

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="?page=categories/list"> '.$page_title.'</a>';

$categories = array();
$main_cats = array();

$results = getCategories();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $categories[] = array(
        "id" => $result['id'],
        "main" => $result['main'],
        "main_name" => array(getMainCategories($result['id'])),
        "name" => $result['name']
    );
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php 

function getCategories() {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `main`,`name` ASC';
    $params = array();
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    return $results;
}

function getMainCategories($id) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = ?';
    $params = array($id);
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    if ($results[0]['main'] != 0) {
        $main_cats[] = getMainCategories($results[0]['main']);
    }else{
        $main_cats[] = $results[0]['name'];
   }
   return $main_cats;
}

?>
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $cat['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if ($cat['main'] != 0) {
                    foreach ($cat['main_name'] as $cn) {
                        echo $cn;
                    }
                }
                echo $cat['name']; 
            ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="?page=categories/edit&id=<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>">Edit</a> / 
            <a href="?page=categories/delete&id=<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

This code is not printing anything out for the attached main categories.

`var_dump($cat['main_name'])` = `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "3D Models" } } }`

Comment: is dataQuery() ok?

Comment: what you mean is it ok?

Comment: Did you check the var_dump of the dataQuery()?

Comment: `var_dump($cat['main_name'])` = `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "3D Models" } } }` so i am casting to array 1 or 2 too many times?

Comment: The way you used recursive function is a little fishy.

Comment: Show the exact expected output.

Comment: i did in my questions. The expected output is `3D Models > Animals > Farm` i need to look at the current category id and check if `main` is not 0, if its not 0 then that means there is another category attached to it and in that case we need to grab that name as well.

Comment: What does `var_dump($results)` show outside of any function? This is actually the array of categories. No need to nest in `$categories`.

Comment: `array(6) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["main"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(9) "3D Models" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["main"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(8) "Sound FX" } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["main"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(8) "Textures" } [3]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["main"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(7) "Animals" } [4]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["main"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(21) "Comic Book Characters" } [5]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["main"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(4) "Farm" } } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataQuery() is a little bit overhead.

```
function dataQuery(){
   global $dbh;
   try {
        $args  = func_get_args();
        $query = array_shift($args);
        $stmt  = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
   } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();    
   }
 }
```

If I understand your problem correctly, this would give you a better design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maincategories` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcategories` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `main_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `subname` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deepsubcategories` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `main_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subsubname` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `maincategories` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, '3D Models'),
(2, 'Sound FX'),
(3, 'Textures');

INSERT INTO `subcategories` (`id`, `main_id`, `subname`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Animals'),
(2, 1, 'Comic Book Characters'),
(3, 1, 'Farm'),
(4, 2, 'cateunderSoundfx'),
(5, 2, 'cateunderSoundfx2'),
(6, 3, 'catunderTexture'),
(4, 3, 'catunderTexture2');

INSERT INTO `deepsubcategories` (`id`, `main_id`, `subid`, `subsubname`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Farm'),
(2, 1, 2, 'Spiderman Book');
```

and you can normal join and display (see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6584/1)):

```
SELECT m.name as maincat, s.subname as subcat, d.subsubname as deepcat
FROM deepsubcategories d
INNER JOIN maincategories m ON d.main_id=m.id
INNER JOIN subcategories s ON d.subid=s.id
```

Then in php you can normally output like this:

```
function getCategories() {
    $query = 'SELECT m.name as maincat, s.subname as subcat, d.subsubname as deepcat
            FROM deepsubcategories d
            INNER JOIN maincategories m ON d.main_id=m.id
            INNER JOIN subcategories s ON d.subid=s.id';
    $params = array();
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    return $results;
}



foreach (getCategories() as category){
        echo category['maincat'].' > '.category['subcat'].' > '.category['deepcat'].';
   }
```